# using sed in BASH script: replace text with info from system variables (hostname and date)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, bash-scripting

I want to use a bash script to run a backup and then send me an email using ssmtp.  I am trying to make a generic script that I can reuse across different Linux machines.  Below is a snippet of the script where I use sed to replace some placeholder text with `$HOSTNAME` and `$DATE` variables.  For some reason when it's run, I get the email but instead of inserting the hostname and date, it wipes out the placeholders.  Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the section of my script:

```
sed -i -e "s/HNAME/$HOSTNAME/g" backup_notification
sed -i -e "s/DATETIME/$date/g" backup_notification

ssmtp me@domain.org < backup_notification
```

Here's the text file of the notification (`HNAME` and `DATETIME` are the placeholders I want sed to replace with system variable information):

```
To: me@domain.org
From: administrator@webserver.domain.org
Subject: Backup completed

This confirms that backup is completed for HNAME on DATETIME.
```

And here's what the text of the email has (notice that the HNAME and DATETIME placeholders were wiped or replaced with nil.):

```
-----Original Message-----
From: root [mailto:root@domain.org] 
Sent: Thursday, March 10, 2016 1:15 PM
To: Me
Subject: Backup completed

This confirms that the backup is completed for has been renewed on .
```

TIA for any help :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$HOSTNAME and $DATE are not defined as variables by default. Instead, use $(command) to insert the output (stdout) from `command` into the string.

For example, in your case, replace $HOSTNAME with you want to use `$(hostname)` and `$(date)`:

```
sed -i -e "s/HNAME/$(hostname)/g" backup_notification
sed -i -e "s/DATETIME/$(date)/g" backup_notification
```

Also, the `-i` flag on sed will edit your backup_notification template, as pointed out by @user568271.  If you don't want that, you might want to read from it and edit it with a pipe:

```
cat backup_notification | sed -e "s/HNAME/$(hostname)/g" | sed -e "s/DATETIME/$(date)/g" | ssmtp me@domain.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the -i switch going to 'edit in place' your message template file.

Won't you need an unaltered version of the template in the backup-notification at the start of the backup process?

As an alternate method, have you considered using an echo with a string that uses the variables of interest piped into your ssmtp command?

```
echo this confirms that backup has been completed and renewed for $HOSTNAME on $DATE | ssmtp me@domain.org
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point.  I tried your suggestion and it works with the $HOSTNAME but for some reason $DATE does nothing.   So the email says "This confirms that backup has been completed on server.domain.org on ."

Comment: @ecube was probably right about needing to use $(hostname) and $(date).  I thought your .bashrc was set up to set the variables.  You should up vote him for the fast response

Comment: You should even mark him as the correct answer, because he used sed like your question asked, as well as being fast

Comment: Thanks to both of you!  Marked answer from @ecube as the correct one since it worked and was the best solution.